# Comparing products using PHP keeping the product on page as cookie

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, cookies

I am trying to make a simple product compare system so far what i have made is that i am able to make it like when i click add to compare button i send jquery ajax request and get a call back response , of that product but i don't know how do it keep the product on page or display the items on compare-container as cookies so when users refresh the product is still there on place my code is like ,

COMPARE.PHP

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.compare').click(function(){
    a = this.parentNode.getAttribute('data-compare-id');
       $.get('post.php?id='+a,status,foo);  
    });

    });             
         function foo(data){                  
         console.log();             
         }             
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

         <?php         
    mysql_connect("localhost",'root','GoogleFacebook') or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('phones') or die(mysql_error());
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mobiles");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

         echo "<div class='phone' data-compare-id='".$row['id']."' style='display:inline-block;margin:10px;border:1px solid #ddd;padding:10px;' >";
         echo "<a href='".$row['phone_a']."' >";
         echo $row['phone_name']."</br>";
         echo "<img src='".$row['phone_img']."' />";
         echo "</br>";
         echo "</a>";
         echo "<button class='compare'>Compare</button>";
         echo "</div>";        
    }
    ?>

         <div class='compare_container'> 
         </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

***post.php***

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'){
$id = $_GET['id'];
mysql_connect("localhost",'root','GoogleFacebook') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('phones') or die(mysql_error());
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mobiles WHERE id='$id'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
echo "<img src='".$row['phone_img']."' />";
echo "<span>".$row['phone_name']."</span>";}
?>
```

I got confused how do i keep the contents on the page

Answer (score 0):

```
$.get('post.php?id='+$(this).parent().attr('data-compare-id'),function (data) { 
    $('.compare_container').append(data);
},'html');
```

If you're using jquery, you should be using $() to find your dom elements.  The code above will do an ajax get call to the post.php and fetch your html.  It will pass the result through the function as the data variable and then you append that data to the container.

You have further issues with your code though.  You should be escaping all get tokens to avoid SQL injection and it is a best practice to use mysqli (improved) versus just mysql.  You should also avoid doing SELECT * to avoid using excessive resources on the database--use SELECT phone_img,phone_name instead.

Also upon further review, you're loading jquery 1.11.2 when the latest version is 2+, which is likely causing you problems.

Comment: i am able to append the product but how to keep the product in compare_container using cookies ,security is not the prob i am doing all that in localhost , on live site i will use mysql_real_escape_string and i mistakenly used that old version of jquery

Comment: The simplest method, in my opinion, is going to be use a session variable.  Store the id values in a session variable as an array and if they refresh the page, use the array to display the values.  You are hitting the server with the ajax get request each time, so just use array_push to add the id to a session variable.